# Aws data transfer costs command line (or web)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, data-transfer, elastic-ip

I am looking to build a POC for my current gig. It is an AWS ec2 with an application that needs to talk with internal AWS private IP's and several outside AWS public IP's.

After benchmarking, I am able to get all the costs for an hour of running this application except for the network data transfer cost. (All from the command line)

Does anyone have an idea on how to get current network costs from either the command line or web interface?

Answer (score 1):

The only potential cost for data transfer between Amazon EC2 instances in the same region would be 1c/GB in & 1c/GB out if using Public IP addresses or going across AZs.

Traffic between instances via private IP addresses in the same AZ would be zero.

For reference, see https://www.duckbillgroup.com/resources/:

[image: AWS Data Transfer costs]

Comment: That chart is super handy!

Answer (score 0):

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/using-aws-cost-explorer-to-analyze-data-transfer-costs/

In Cost Explorer using filters you can analyze data transfer costs:

After your cost allocation tags have been activated, and your workloads have run for at least a day, you can use filters in Cost Explorer to analyze your costs over that period.

1. Sign in to AWS Cost Explorer at https://console.aws.amazon.com/cost-reports/home?#/
2. Choose Explore in the navigation pane, and then choose Cost and Usage.
3. Choose the date range for the period for which you want to see the costs, and choose the Apply button.
4. Choose Filters – Service, then EC2-instances, and then EC2-ELB.Next choose Apply filters.
5. To see the total EC2 data transfer cost:

Choose Filters, Usage Type Group, EC2: Data Transfer – inter-Availability Zone, Internet (Out), and Region to Region (Out), then choose Apply filters.

You can also choose each individual data transfer type by checking only the box for that type.

[image]

Comment: I was trying to avoid using Cost Explorer. .01 per request and if you have Hourly detail enabled, more $$. Annoying that I cannot CLI my way to get per interface, TCO. I do understand the challenge that AWS (and other clouds) would have to update a LONG counter accurately.  Thanks for the answer, I will have the team I am working with enable CE for the account I am working on.